# JQuery/JS - Delay animation by section

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I Have this script to animate icons on the screen with a delay between each icon.

The script Works fine, but it Always animate each icon on screen with the same delay.

**THE PROBLEM:**

-If I have 10 icons on screen I will have 10s to end all animation - but if I have 200 icons on screen, I will need 200s to end.. (much time to wait)

**WHAT I NEED**

A way to control the delay according the number of icons on screen.

OR a way to control the delay by section (because I know how many icons are in each section)

example:

In section Solutions: I have 10 icons - then a 1s delay for each icon will be 10s total.

In section Clients: I have 100 icons - then a 1s delay for each icon will be 100s total.. then, I need a "custom delay" here - like 10ms to make all animation faster.

any idea? (I'm a beginner in JS)

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);

const MULTIPLIER = 800; //millis

var countInView = 0; 
var timeouts = [];
for (i = 0; i < $animation_elements.length; i++)  
    timeouts[i] = [];


function check_if_in_view() {
  var window_height = $window.height();
  var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
  var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height + 15);

  for(var i=0; i < $animation_elements.length ; i++) {
    var $element = $animation_elements.eq(i);
    var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
    var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
    var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);


    //check to see if this current container is within viewport
    if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {


      // If is icon and it wasn't already in view range(in-view).
      if($element.is($('i').parent()) && !$element.hasClass('in-view')) {
        var delay = MULTIPLIER * ++countInView; //adds +1

        //Pause animation.
        $element.addClass('paused');
        // Clojure for passing outer values to timeout
        (function(delay, $element, savedtimeout){
          // Keeps a reference of the timeout to remove it later.
          savedtimeout[i][0] = setTimeout(function() {
            //Start animation
            $element.removeClass('paused');
            countInView--;
          }, delay);
        }(delay, $element, timeouts));
      }
      $element.addClass('in-view'); //always
    } else {

      // If element wasn't already in view range(in-view).
      if($element.hasClass('in-view')) {
        $element.removeClass('in-view');
      }
      if($element.hasClass('paused')) {
        if(timeouts[i][0] != null) {
          //Removes the timeout from the queue
          clearTimeout(timeouts[i][0]);
          countInView--;
        }

        $element.removeClass('paused');
      } // end if

    } // end if
  } // end for
}
$window.on('scroll resize', check_if_in_view);
$window.trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: You can't just use this: `number of icons * 1(s)`?

Comment: Hi @MehdiDehghani tks for your time! I'm not so expert in JS but I try this idea using $animation_elements.length - but this give me the TOTAL number of icons on entire page. (not only on section or only on screen) how can I get the number of icons on a section?

Comment: Please share you `HTML` code, then I can tell you exactly how you can get each section's icons.

Comment: I will create a jsfiddle right now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery parents() to find the parent section of the icon, and set the delay accordingly.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parents.asp

Example:

```
var $elementParentSection = $animation_elements.parents('.section-class-name');

if($elementParentSection.hasClass('.section-class-name'))
    delay = 10;
```

Comment: Hi @Jacob-Goh, first of all, tks for your time! I will try this and feedback here as soon as possible! tks a lot!! Just a dummie question (I'm a begginer with JS) - '.section-class-name' is the section id or I need to create a class for each section?

Comment: no. in jquery, use dots `$('.class-name')` to select element with class-name. use #  `$('#id-name')` to select element with id.  'section-class-name' is a class, not  id. so in this case, you need to add the class name for the parent sections too, in order to use the 'hasClass()' function

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have following structure:

```
<div class="section">
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
    <i class="animation-element"></i>
</div>
```

Then you can use `$('.section .animation-element').length`, this will give you `4` & `5` as result, because you have 4 `.animation-element` in first `section` & 5 `animation-element` in second section.

Then you can use this: `number of .animation-element` as your delay, I ignore `* 1s`, because `N * 1 = N` :)

BTW if you don't want to re-write your entire code, you can add `data attribute` (for ex. `data-number-of-icons`) to hold each section's icon number (add this to `.section`s), then in your `for loon` in `check_if_in_view`, you can access to the `data attribute` like this:

```
var delay = $element.closest('.section').data('number-of-icons');
```

Hope this help.

**Update**

Based on our conversation & your `jsfiddle`, the solution will be something like this:
You need to change `MULTIPLIER` depends of icon's count. for example, for `1 to 10` icons, `MULTIPLIER = 250`, for `10 to 50` icons, `MULTIPLIER = 100` and so on. you can get `icon's count` using my mentioned solution.

Comment: Hi @Mehdi-Dehghani! I create a simple https://jsfiddle.net/quq2q9cg/1/ - It has a CLICK HERE to "stop" the animation (because the icons only start to animate when it appears on the screen). THen I create 2 sections. One with 3 icons.. other with more icons (but imagine this section with 100 icons).. both sections has the same delay between each icon.. I'll test your solution right now.. feedback you soon!! tks!

Comment: Nice, thanks, I just checked, please explain what is wrong with your jsfiddle?

Comment: I think the solution is more easy... explain the problem is the hard part.. :D - The animation script has a "const MULTIPLIER = 800" fixed. If I manually change this value for 10 (const MULTIPLIER = 10) - will be perfect for the section with 100 icons (The Client Section). Because with this, in this section all icons will be animated with 10 milliseconds delay BETWEEN each icon.. then I will have 100 * 10 ms = 1000ms = 1 s only. If I use the 800 ms - I will have 100 * 800 ms = 80s (1 min and 20 s waiting)...

Comment: But, if I use 10 ms for the first section (with only 3 icons) - the animation will be very very fast.. (sometimes you cannot see any animation, because its so fast with only 3 icons). - but if you use 800ms x 3 icons = 2400 ms = 2.4 s. Perfect to see!

Comment: do you understand? I need a way to change this MULTIPLIER - if I'm on section 1 (MULTIPLIER = 800) or section 2 (MULTIPLIER = 10).

Comment: I think you need some formula for computing the `MULTIPLIER`, for example, for `1 to 10` icons, the `MULTIPLIER= 250` is perfect, for `10 to 50`, `MULTIPLIER = 100` and so on. in fact you need to test this values to achieve best formula. then you can just use `number of icons` with that formula. a I right?

Comment: yes! this will be perfect! I was thinking something like "if section is clients then MULTIPLIER is 10 - else - Multiplier is 800" - but your idea is much better, will cover more situations..